# What to interpret from dd command in terms of performance?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to compare the performance of various kernel running in power pc. Here is one of my test.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024 count=1000000
```

I see that in one of the kernel version it took -

```
 8.595918 seconds, 113.6MB/s
```

and in another kernel version, it took -

```
 8.182470 seconds, 119.3MB/s
```

My question is my test is basically reading from RAM and writing on to /dev/null. What I can interpret from this in terms of the system? What can I interpret about the bottleneck. If the data is not sufficient what else I could do to get some meaningful information.

Comment: Never use single runs of anything to compare performance. Take averages of multiple runs.

Answer (score 0):

The 5% difference can be considered noise, in other words you can't conclude that there is a difference between the two test results. Don't forget that other processes than `dd` are running and occasionally using the CPU, and the environments of the two tests are not identical.

Perhaps real time priority for the test process and repeating the tests a few times gives you better data. In any case, the bottleneck is the CPU and memory access. There is no I/O.

Comment: the bottleneck in that is very likely to be the system call overhead, not the CPU and memory bandwidth needed to actually copy that 1 GB around

Comment: Sure, 1000000 system calls is a lot. There is a lot of room for improvement by increasing the block size and decreasing the block count.

Answer (score 0):

> What I can interpret from this in terms of the system?

You can interpret that `dd` copying data from `/dev/zero` to `/dev/null`, in 1024-byte blocks can do it at a rate of around 115 MB/s. Not much else.

Each block `dd` copies requires making two system calls, one to `read()`, one to `write()`. And those system calls have overhead, which is likely to have a significant effect at 1024 bytes per call. With that small a block rate, you're not measuring the speed the system could transfer blocks of zeroes around. But you're also not measuring the raw system call overhead, since there still *are* those 1024 bytes to process for each call, plus whatever necessary bookkeeping the IO calls have. It's not exactly like calling `getpid()` either.